# Aligning text and formulas in an inference table

Tags: tables, align

I have the following 'table':

```
\begin{align}
1.&\gamma   &\text{Hyp}\nonumber\\
2.&\neg \gamma &\text{Hyp}\nonumber\\
3.&(\gamma\implies(\neg\alpha\implies \gamma))&\text{AX1}\nonumber\\
4.&(\neg\alpha\implies\gamma)&\text{MP (1,3)}\nonumber\\
5.&(\neg \gamma \implies (\neg \alpha \implies \neg \gamma))&\text{AX1}\nonumber\\
6.&(\neg \alpha \implies \neg \gamma)&\text{MP(2,5)}\nonumber\\
7.&((\neg \alpha \implies\neg \gamma) \implies ((\neg \alpha \implies \gamma)\implies \alpha))&\text{AX3}\nonumber\\
8.&((\neg \alpha \implies \gamma) \implies \alpha)) &\text{MP(6,7)}\nonumber\\
9.& \alpha.&\text{MP(4,8)}\nonumber
\end{align}
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

I want to have a bit more space between the numbers 1. , 2. , etc and the beggining of the formulas, and also want to have the text in the position where it is now, but aligned on the first letter (I want the words AX1 and MP(1,3) to have the "A" and "M" in the same 'column').

Is there any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `alignat*` (the * version  saves you from typing 9 times`\nonumber`), or with a `tabular` environment:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{3}
  1. & \quad & & \gamma & & \text{Hyp} \\
  2. & & & \neg \gamma & & \text{Hyp} \\
  3. & & & (\gamma\implies(\neg\alpha\implies \gamma)) & & \text{AX1} \\
  4. & & & (\neg\alpha\implies\gamma) & & \text{MP (1,3)} \\
  5. & & & (\neg \gamma \implies (\neg \alpha \implies \neg \gamma)) & & \text{AX1} \\
  6. & & & (\neg \alpha \implies \neg \gamma) & & \text{MP(2,5)} \\
  7. & & & ((\neg \alpha \implies\neg \gamma) \implies ((\neg \alpha \implies \gamma)\implies \alpha)) & \qquad & \text{AX3} \\
  8. & & & ((\neg \alpha \implies \gamma) \implies \alpha)) & & \text{MP(6,7)} \\
  9. & & & \alpha. & & \text{MP(4,8)}
\end{alignat*}
\vskip1cm

\newcounter{rowcnt}\setcounter{rowcnt}{0}
\begin{tabular}{>{\refstepcounter{rowcnt}\therowcnt.\quad$}l<{$}@{\qquad}l}
      \gamma & Hyp \\
      \neg \gamma & Hyp \\
      (\gamma\implies(\neg\alpha\implies \gamma)) & AX1 \\
      (\neg\alpha\implies\gamma) & MP (1,3) \\
      (\neg \gamma \implies (\neg \alpha \implies \neg \gamma)) & AX1 \\
      (\neg \alpha \implies \neg \gamma) & MP(2,5) \\
      ((\neg \alpha \implies\neg \gamma) \implies ((\neg \alpha \implies \gamma)\implies \alpha)) & AX3 \\
      ((\neg \alpha \implies \gamma) \implies \alpha)) &MP(6,7) \\
      \alpha. & MP(4,8)
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot!

Could you explain a bit why you used three '&' in all the lines but the first (where you used a &, a \quad and two more &s)? If I used only two &s in the lines below, it would break the table and I don't understand why.

Comment: For k alignment groups, you need 2k – 1 `&`: from the second group, a first `&` introduces the group, the second `&` sets the alignment point inside that  group. Note it would be as simple to use a `tabular` environment, with an automatic numbering of rows.

Comment: I see, thanks Bernard, I had I seen the tabular environment, but I didn't quite get how to do stuff like this. I have a last question, if I change one of the numbers, to a two(or more) digit numbers, they get aligned towards the rightmost digit, is there a way to align them to the left (just as the text)?

Comment: For the tabular solution, I've updated my answer.  For the problem of two-digit numbers, I'll try to see what can be done, but in my opinion, it looks better if right-aligned.

Comment: Yes, I thought about if for a while and it will look better this way (else I'd have to align all the dots to the position of the dot of the biggest number, and that would look bad), so don't lose any more time with it. Thanks a lot!